# Specific input conflicts in a form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

```
<?php

$myArray = [1,2,3,4];
$myID = 1;

foreach ($myArray as $key) { ?>
<form method="post" name="form">
   <input id="userID" name="userID" value="<?php echo $myID; ?>" />
   <input id="myValue" name="myValue" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" />
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Why the value of myValue inserted in the bdd is always 1 ?

The value of userID changes perfectly..

Comment: It isn't: https://3v4l.org/WScWu but you are creating a new form every time.

Comment: Well as he is using the same `name=""` for every iteration he would need to have a seperate form for each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the value of userID shouldn't change because it's value is always 1

```
$myID = 1;
```

You never change it or operate it. So the value of `userID` always going to be `1`.
I think you are confusing your variables names. Try rechecking your code.

Comment: Yes I was confused about this, because this ID is the ID of the current user and when I tried with an other user it worked. But yes, now I got it : it shouldn't be a thing I have to care about on this problem.